# efficient way of getting a value and avoiding inner loop from two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, performance, big-o

So I have two-dimensional array with huge amount of data and I want to be able to get a particular value from inner array using loop inside loop. Here is example array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Field] => id
            [Type] => int(10)
            [Null] => NO
            [Key] => PRI
            [Default] => 
            [Extra] => auto_increment
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Field] => name
            [Type] => varchar(100)
            [Null] => NO
            [Key] => 
            [Default] => 
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Field] => active
            [Type] => enum('Y','N')
            [Null] => NO
            [Key] => 
            [Default] => Y
            [Extra] => 
        )

)
```

From above array, I want to get the value for the key `Field` only something like this using loop inside loop:

```
$fields = array();
foreach ($columns as $columnSub) {
    foreach ($columnSub as $ckey => $cvalue) {
        if ($ckey === 'Field') {
            $fields[] = $cvalue;
        }
    }
}
```

However since array is big one, this takes quite some time. Is there some quicker way using iterators to pluck the needed element value from above two-dimensional array in an efficient manner please ?

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => name
    [2] => active
)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_column` is sweet.  PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$fields = array_column($columns, 'Field');
```

PHP < 5.5.0:

```
foreach($columns as $array) {
    if(isset($array['Field'])) {
        $fields[] = $array['Field'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$fields = array();

foreach($array as $key => $values) 
{
    $fields[] = $values['Field'];
}

var_dump($fields);
```